# waitpid on ptrace'd non-child thread

Tags: ptrace, waitpid

I have used `ptrace` to force a thread within another process to call
`sys_clone` and create a new thread with pid `pid`, with the clone flags `CLONE_FILES`,
`CLONE_FS`, `CLONE_IO`, `CLONE_PTRACE`, `CLONE_SIGHAND`, `CLONE_THREAD` and
`CLONE_VM`.

As I understand from the `ptrace` man-page, waitpid() is valid on children
processes and ptrace'd processes. However, the following code in my program
succeeds:

```
assert(ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL) != -1);
assert(waitpid(pid, NULL, WSTOPPED) == -1);
printf("error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Output:

```
error: No child processes
```

Why could this be? I have checked that when the ptrace is removed, the child
thread terminates on a breakpoint instruction (0xcc).